# How to use Linq Any() in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, linq, c++-cli

I want to replicate the C# code in C++Cli, but i didnt found any "Any()" linq example on google nor in stackoverflow

**C# Code**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var grettings = new List<string>()
            {
                "Hey",
                "Hi",
                "How"
            };

            var currentGreeting = "Hey are you ok ?";

            var b = grettings.Any(a => currentGreeting.Contains(a));

            if (b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a greeting");
            }
        }
```

**C++ CLi attempt**

```
static bool Lambda(String^ lambdaObj, String^ objName)
            {
                return objName->Contains(lambdaObj);
            }

static MinionType GetMinionType(obj_AI_Minion^ minion)
            {
                if(minion != nullptr)
                {
                    auto skinName = minion->CharDataInfo->BaseSkinName;
                    auto any = Enumerable::Any(LaneMinionsNames, gcnew Func<String^, String^, bool>(&Lambda));
                    if(any)
                    {

                    }
                }
                return None;
            };
```

**Error**

[image: Error message]

Comment: Why would the C++-CLI lambda take 2 arguments when the C# version takes only 1?

Comment: Well i dont know how to access the "a" that i did on C# on c++cli to check if the name contains it, that is my strugle

Comment: You would have to create a managed class and add the string as a member, then your function becomes a non-static member of that class. This is what the C# compiler usually does under the hood to capture a variable.

Comment: I am kind of new on C++Cli could you give me any snippet or example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a lambda here.

Simplified C# version:

```
var b = greetings.Any(currentGreeting.Contains);
```

and because this is capture-free, the C++/CLI version is simple:

```
auto b = Enumerable::Any(greetings,
                         gcnew Func<String^, bool>(currentGreeting,
                                                   &System::String::Contains));
```

Comment: Thank you so much , just correcting you on the C# version remove "a => " and it works

Comment: @MárioGabriel: oops, I did mean no lambda and then the code still had one.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda-ish function needs to be :

```
static bool Lambda(String^ objName)
        {
            return currentGreeting->Contains(lambdaObj);
        }
```

Exactly how you can get `currentGreeting` in there is beyond my knowledge ot C++/CLI,

UPDATE: OK, this works in C#:

```
void Main()
{
    var grettings = new List<string>()
            {
                "Hey",
                "Hi",
                "How"
            };

    var currentGreeting = "Hey are you ok ?";

    var b = grettings.Any(BundleLambda(currentGreeting) );
    b.Dump();
}

public static Func<string, bool> BundleLambda(string target)
{
    return a=> target.Contains(a);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is what i need, thanks anyway for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

I found it necessary to use a "Helper" class.
Here is an example that is a little more complex where it checks two arrays of strings against each other to see if one array contains a substring of the strings in another array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Linq;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper class to manage the String::Contains where a higher scope string
// is presented for comparison
public ref class CHelperStringContains
{
private:
   static property String^ _strPiece;
   static bool _contains(String^ str) { return str->Contains(_strPiece); }

public:
   CHelperStringContains(String^ strPiece) { _strPiece = strPiece; }
   Func<String^, bool>^ Contains = gcnew Func<String^, bool>(_contains);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper class to manage IEnumerable::Contains where a higher scope
// IEnumerable::String is presented for comparison
public ref class CHelperArrayContains
{
private:
   static property IEnumerable<String^>^ _arr_strSources;
   static bool _anyContains(String^ strPiece)
   {
      return Enumerable::Any<String^>(_arr_strSources, (gcnew CHelperStringContains(strPiece))->Contains);
   }

public:
   CHelperArrayContains(IEnumerable<String^>^ arr_strSources) { _arr_strSources = arr_strSources; }
   Func<String^, bool>^ AnyContains = gcnew Func<String^, bool>(_anyContains);
};

int main(void)
{  // Warning Level 4 / Warnings as Errors
   IEnumerable<String^>^ arr_strSources = gcnew array<String^>{ "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta" };
   IEnumerable<String^>^ arr_strPieces = gcnew array<String^>{ "phha", "lie", "zelt" };
   //--------------------------- MEAT ----------------------------------------
   // Check to see if any of the sources contain any of the substring pieces
   // How it looks in C#
   // bool blnRetVal = arr_strPieces.Any(strPiece => arr_strSources.Any(strData => strData.Contains(strPiece)));
   bool blnRetVal = Enumerable::Any<String^>(arr_strPieces, (gcnew CHelperArrayContains(arr_strSources))->AnyContains);
   System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Found = {0}", blnRetVal);
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `static` here, it ruins thread safety for no benefit.  (And in other single threaded cases, loss of reentrancy may be a problem)